# Borderless Form with BorderIcons (like Office 2016 Applications)

Tags: forms, delphi, borderless

I am currently searching for a way to make my form look like the office 2016 applications (e. g. Excel 2016).

[image]

They don't have the typical Windows titlebar but they still have what is called the BorderIcons in Delphi (Minimize-, Maximize- and Close-Buttons). I am wondering if it's possible to replicate this in Delphi 10.2. 
I for sure definetly need a borderless form but how do I go about the BorderIcons? Currently I am working with Images, they change when the mouse enters and when it leaves.

[image]

It's not the greates solution, there has to be a better way, does someone of you guys have an idea?

Same goes for the shadow of the Office 2016 applications, I have absolutely no idea how to do that...
Thanks in advance for any ideas!

Comment: @downvoters: Wasn't there an unspoken rule to comment when downvoting? And wasn't there recently a blog post about StackOverflow having to become more friendly? There are two down votes without a single comment. How is the OP to know if he made a mistake of how to possibly improve his question?

Comment: it has to do with styling. 1) the shadow is applicable but you will need to do a lot of API coding 2) same thing for the border Icons you will need pictures any way for custom ones. you can draw them programmatically on the non client area.

Comment: Wouldn't [form like this](https://i.imgur.com/gY87YiR.png) suffice (it's focused state of a form from Windows 7)?

Comment: @Nasreddine, how would you want to draw DWM drop shadow by yourself (assuming you say it requires a lot of API code)?

Answer (score 3):

I also was trying to find a solution to have a DWM shadow and either no borders at all or borders with their minimal size (for 1 px.). After some researches I can conclude that such a task may be completed successfuly (I meant to have shadow around form that has minimal visible borders).

Some code below demonstrates how to achieve this goal with a minimal code size.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, DwmAPI, Vcl.ExtCtrls, Vcl.Buttons;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    Panel1: TPanel;
    SpeedButton1: TSpeedButton;
    SpeedButton2: TSpeedButton;
    SpeedButton3: TSpeedButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure SpeedButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    procedure CreateAlphaChannel(ABmpIn: TBitmap; Alpha: Byte);
    procedure WndProc(var Message: TMessage); override;

  public
    { Public declarations }
    Active: Boolean;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Active := false;
end;

procedure TForm1.SpeedButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Close;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Flag: LongInt;
begin
  if Active then
    Exit;

  if HandleAllocated then
    begin
      Active := true;
      Flag := DWMNCRP_ENABLED;
      DwmSetWindowAttribute(Handle, DWMWA_ALLOW_NCPAINT, @Flag, SizeOf(Flag));
      SetWindowPos(Handle, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE or SWP_NOSIZE or SWP_NOSENDCHANGING or SWP_FRAMECHANGED);
    end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Flag: LongInt;
begin
  if not Active then
    Exit;

  if HandleAllocated then
    begin
      Active := false;
      Flag := DWMNCRP_DISABLED;
      DwmSetWindowAttribute(Handle, DWMWA_ALLOW_NCPAINT, @Flag, SizeOf(Flag));

      SetWindowPos(Handle, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE or SWP_NOSIZE or SWP_NOACTIVATE or SWP_NOSENDCHANGING or SWP_DRAWFRAME or SWP_FRAMECHANGED);
      RedrawWindow(Handle, nil, 0, RDW_INVALIDATE or RDW_UPDATENOW or RDW_ERASE or RDW_FRAME);
      SendMessage(Handle, WM_NCPAINT, 1, 0);
    end;
end;

procedure TForm1.CreateAlphaChannel(ABmpIn: TBitmap; Alpha: Byte);
type
  TRGBAQuad = Record
    Blue: Byte;
    Green: Byte;
    Red: Byte;
    Alpha: Byte;
  end;

const
  Max = MaxInt div SizeOf(TRGBAQuad) - 1;

type
  PRGBAArray    = ^TRGBAArray;
  TRGBAArray = Array [0..Max-1] of TRGBAQuad;

var
  RowIn: PRGBAArray;
  X: Integer;
  Y: Integer;
  DeltaAlpha: Byte;
begin
  if not Assigned(ABmpIn) or (ABmpIn.PixelFormat <> pf32bit) then
    Exit;

  DeltaAlpha := Trunc(Alpha * (1 / MaxByte));
  for Y:=0 to ABmpIn.Height - 1 do
    begin
      RowIn := ABmpIn.ScanLine[Y];
      for X:=0 to ABmpIn.Width - 1 do
        begin
          RowIn[X].Blue := RowIn[X].Blue * DeltaAlpha;
          RowIn[X].Green := RowIn[X].Green * DeltaAlpha;
          RowIn[X].Red := RowIn[X].Red * DeltaAlpha;
          RowIn[X].Alpha := Alpha;
        end;
    end;
end;

procedure TForm1.WndProc(var Message: TMessage);
var
  Bmp: TBitmap;
  R: TRect;
  DC: HDC;
  AB: TBlendFunction;
  SavedDC: Integer;
begin
  case Message.Msg of
    WM_NCPAINT:
      begin
        Inherited WndProc(Message);

        if Active then
          begin
            if HandleAllocated then
              begin
                // Obtain context to draw within
                DC := GetWindowDC(Handle);
                try
                  // Prepare bitmap that contains graphical image of borders
                  Bmp := TBitmap.Create;
                  Bmp.SetSize(Width, Height);
                  Bmp.PixelFormat := pf32bit;
                  try
                    // Draw on this bitmap something useful (f.e. just fill it with solid color)
                    Bmp.Canvas.Brush.Color := $467321;
                    Bmp.Canvas.FillRect(Bmp.Canvas.ClipRect);

                    // Paint text
                    Bmp.Canvas.Font.Size := 14;
                    Bmp.Canvas.Font.Style := [fsBold];
                    Bmp.Canvas.Font.Color := clWhite;
                    Bmp.Canvas.TextOut(16, 32, 'Form Shadow');

                    Bmp.Canvas.Font.Size := 11;
                    Bmp.Canvas.Font.Style := [];
                    Bmp.Canvas.TextOut(16, 66, 'built with DWM API');

                    // IMPORTANT! This routine fills bitmap with alpha
                    // that needs for AlphaBlend function to properly
                    // draw our bitmap.
                    // Just comment CreateAlphaChannel(Bmp, 255) below
                    // and run the example - you will see what I meant.
                    CreateAlphaChannel(Bmp, 255);

                    // Set up special structure to output bitmap respecting its alpha
                    AB.BlendOp := AC_SRC_OVER;
                    AB.BlendFlags := 0;
                    AB.SourceConstantAlpha := 255;
                    AB.AlphaFormat := AC_SRC_ALPHA;

                    // Exclude ClientArea of form to avoid its overpainting
                    R := Rect(1, 1, Width - 1, Height - 1);
                    SavedDC := SaveDC(DC);
                    try
                      ExcludeClipRect(DC, {R.Left,}240, R.Top, R.Right, R.Bottom);

                      WinAPI.Windows.AlphaBlend(DC, 0, 0, Bmp.Width, Bmp.Height, Bmp.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, Bmp.Width, Bmp.Height, AB);
                    finally
                      RestoreDC(DC, SavedDC);
                    end;
                  finally
                    Bmp.Free;
                  end;
                finally
                  ReleaseDC(Handle, DC);
                end;
              end;
          end;
      end;
    WM_EXITSIZEMOVE, WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED:
      begin
        Inherited WndProc(Message);

        // Repaint our borders
        if Active then
          begin
            if HandleAllocated then
              SendMessage(Handle, WM_NCPAINT, 1, 0);
          end;
      end;
    WM_NCCALCSIZE:
      begin
        Inherited WndProc(Message);

        if Active then
          begin
            if TWMNCCALCSIZE(Message).CalcValidRects then
              begin
                // This value at right side (7 and 29) just a size of borders of form under enabled Aero.
                // Usually this values should be 8 but without non-client area Aero eefects will not work.
                // So we must to leave at least 1 pixel of default NC-area around form.
                // IMPORTANT! 29 is a cumulative value of 7 (top border of form) and caption
                // height (by default - it is set to 22 px.).
                Dec(TWMNCCALCSIZE(Message).CalcSize_Params.rgrc[0].Left, 7);
                Inc(TWMNCCALCSIZE(Message).CalcSize_Params.rgrc[0].Right, 7);
                Dec(TWMNCCALCSIZE(Message).CalcSize_Params.rgrc[0].Top, 29);
                Inc(TWMNCCALCSIZE(Message).CalcSize_Params.rgrc[0].Bottom, 7);
              end;
          end;
      end;
    else
      Inherited WndProc(Message);
  end;
end;


end.
```

DFM:

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 290
  ClientWidth = 556
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  OnCreate = FormCreate
  DesignSize = (
    556
    290)
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object Button1: TButton
    Left = 330
    Top = 250
    Width = 97
    Height = 32
    Caption = 'Apply shadow!'
    TabOrder = 0
    OnClick = Button1Click
  end
  object Button2: TButton
    Left = 433
    Top = 250
    Width = 113
    Height = 32
    Caption = 'Return state back!'
    TabOrder = 1
    OnClick = Button2Click
  end
  object Panel1: TPanel
    Left = 239
    Top = 0
    Width = 322
    Height = 26
    Anchors = [akLeft, akTop, akRight]
    BevelOuter = bvNone
    Color = 4616993
    ParentBackground = False
    TabOrder = 2
    object SpeedButton1: TSpeedButton
      Left = 304
      Top = 2
      Width = 23
      Height = 22
      Caption = 'X'
      OnClick = SpeedButton1Click
    end
    object SpeedButton2: TSpeedButton
      Left = 282
      Top = 2
      Width = 23
      Height = 22
      Caption = '?'
    end
    object SpeedButton3: TSpeedButton
      Left = 260
      Top = 2
      Width = 23
      Height = 22
      Caption = '_'
    end
  end
end
```

I have written some comments in the code to illustrate moments that I consider important to know. Obviously, lots of these comments have information that is not useful, but I gave it a try :)

Now compile example and press button 'Apply shadow!'. You will encountered with a form that looks like on the image below:
[image]

Looks wonderful, isn't it? But don't be too fast - now press 'Return state back!' and you will see very bad effect, such as on screen below:
[image]

Really, I don't have any clue what I should do to avoid this graphical artifact. The only option is to minimize and restore window. This allows `Windows` to paint our form correctly now, but try to change bounds of restored form, f.e. from right side.
  Do you see? If not then look at the picture below:
[image]

Let me explain this picture.
Left most red arrow shows that form "has lost" its caption. The second right top arrow confirms that mouse pointer is over `Maximize` button. The last one arrow indicates the `white space` over NC-area of form.

We can observe that NC-area of right side has painted in white color, but we already disable our painting mechanism and `Windows` is now paints NC-area.
After some researches I found that there is a problem with call to `DwmSetWindowAttribute(Handle, DWMWA_ALLOW_NCPAINT, @Flag, SizeOf(Flag))` with `Flag` set to `DWMNCRP_ENABLED` and in another handler `Flag` set to `DWMNCRP_DISABLED`.

You can reproduce described problem if wipe out all code inside `WndProc` and leave only inherited handler. Now run program, activate shadow, deactivate it and try to change right side of form again. It again produces white color over NC-area of form's right side as was stated above. This is the only (for now) limitation of using approach provided in this example.

**P.S.**
Perhaps I was blind while read question because I answer only part of it. The problem with buttons could be solved as described below:
1. Place a `TPanel` control on form.
2. Add as much buttons (or other controls) on `TPanel` as you need.
3. Assign handlersto these controls.
4. "Play" with `TPanel`: because of excluding NC-borders, panel in design-time should be placed carefully to be fully visible in run-time. Suppose you will not move `TPanel` often; you should place andfill it with control once and leave it alone.
Image below demonstrates what I meant:
[image]

You can see how `TPanel` is placed to looks nice on result form with minimal NC-area.

After some manipulation, our form have this "style":
[image]

Try to click "title" button witn caption "X".

If you want to "style" form in more elegant way, then you definitely should create a component (non-visual, I think) that will play a role of a controller of form: applies DWM shadow, allocates `TPanel` with buttons etc. Then you should use hook to know if form was created (this is useful if project contains lots of form). For more info about hooks, please, use third link.
When you use hook you will know that form has been created and you will be able to allocate an instance of your controller on that form. This allows you to "style" any form of your application (even if such a form was created programmaticaly) "on-the-go".

Hope you understand that the code above is not a finished project. There are a huge amount of possibilities to add new features, eliminate some bugs etc. For example, moving form by mouse pointer is not implemented.

And also one thing that deserves your attention: you must check if your program is running under `Windows 7` (at least) to provide shadow. Otherwise under `XP`, f.e., form will not have shadow at all. And I don't know what about `Win 8`, `Win 8.1`, `Win 10` (probably I missed something?). In my opinion, you will need test your program under all `Windows OS`, Yes, one more: I don't test this example under `Windows Vista`. There are could be detected some strange bugs, I suppose, because of early DWM versions. But this just private opinion.

Useful links:
[Microsoft's DWM API reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa969499(v=vs.85).aspx)
[AlphaBlend function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/dd183351(v=vs.85).aspx)
[CBTProc callback function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms644977(v=vs.85).aspx)

**P.S.S.**
I am pretty sure there is lots of grammatical mistakes and errors in text, so take my apologizes about it ;)